# Python regex to catch digits group at the begining or end of the sequence of letters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, validation

Hey everyone I'm new to python. I'm trying to identify an input using python can anybody help?

Validate username with this constraints.

1. username should be 8-12 characters.
2. must contain numbers and lowercase character only
3. should have only two numbers, can be at the end or at the beginning of the username

example: `12username`

this what I got so far.

```
import re 

def identify_usr(): 
    uname = input("input username: ")
    reg = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\d)[0-9a-z]{8,12}$"

    pat = re.compile(reg)
    match = re.search(pat, uname)

    if match:
        print("Username is valid")
    else :
        print("Username is Invalid")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    identify_usr()
```

output

> input username: 66jkdk
>
> Username is valid

but it still doesn't have the specification above, "only two numbers, can be at the end or at the beginning of the username"
any idea would be much appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: You don't have to do everything with one regular expression. You can have one call to the length() function to make sure that the string is between 8 and 12 characters, one regex to verify that it's all numbers and lowercase, and one regex to verify that it only has two numbers, and that they are at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex can be used:

```
/^(?:[a-z]{6,10}\d{2}|\d{2}[a-z]{6,10})$/
```

These string match the regex:

```
"abcdefgh45"
"45abcdefgh"
```

These do not:

```
"2acdefgh45"
"45abcdefghijk" 
"abcdefghijk45"
"abcde45"
```

The regex can be made self-documenting by writing it in free-spacing mode.

```
re.compile(r"""^     # match beginning of string
  (?:                # begin non-capture group
    [a-z]{6,10}\d{2} # match 6-10 lc letters followed by 2 digits
    |                # or
    \d{2}[a-z]{6,10} # match 2 digits followed by 6-10 lc letters
  )                  # end non-capture group
$                    # match end of string""", re.X)
```

`re.X` is the short form of `re.verbose`.

Comment: awesome, you explained every purpose of the regex. the free-spacing mode is new to me. i'll try to figure out based on your explanations.
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems suspiciously complex. How about the following one?

```
^([a-z]{6,10}\d{2})|(\d{2}[a-z]{6,10})$
```

Which [correctly identifies](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Ba-z%5D%7B6%2C10%7D%5Cd%7B2%7D)%7C(%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Ba-z%5D%7B6%2C10%7D)&test_string=66jkdk&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) your example as invalid.

Comment: this answer work right away. and cary's answer also give me insight for how to explain this code.
thank you guys, you are awesome.

Comment: There is a problem here. Due to the lack of anchors your regex will incorrectly match strings having more than 12 characters, such as `”12zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz”`.

Comment: @carySwoveland yes indeed, and i implement your answer as well to give the regex anchors